# Смена версии php в Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Привет
Нужно поменять версию **php** с 7 на 5.6 на Ubuntu.

В Ubuntu только 2 день, поэтому сильно не разбираюсь

Comment: Какая версия убунты, кстати? 16?

Comment: да, версия 16.04

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

**Сначала удалим все PHP библиотеки**

```
sudo apt-get purge php *
```

Затем добавляем PPA с которого будем качать PHP т.к. в стандартном `apt-get` есть только последняя седьмая версия по умолчанию В Ubuntu 16.04. `apt` это пакетный менеджер в Ubuntu, из него мы устанавливаем программы, пакеты, библиотеки и т.д. Следующей командой мы добавляем в него адрес PPA откуда он выкачает нам нужный PHP-5.6.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Если выдаст ошибку `add-apt-repository: command not found`

То нужно выполнить следующую команду

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Далее выполняем две команды последовательно

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Установка PHP 5.6**

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

На этом этапе PHP уже установлен, но чтобы установить дополнительные библиотеки можно ввести:

**Дополнительно**

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
```

**Чтобы найти точные названия библиотек в `apt-get` для фреймворка или при необходимости, пример:**

`apt-cache php`

пример ответа:

```
...
php-zend-code - Zend Framework - Code component
php-zend-db - Zend Framework - Db component
php-zend-eventmanager - Zend Framework - EventManager component
php-zend-hydrator - Zend Framework - Hydrator component
php-zend-search - Zend Framework - ZendSearch component
php-zend-stdlib - Zend Framework - Stdlib component
php-zend-xml - Zend Framework - Xml component
...
```

**Проверка версии PHP**

```
sudo php -v
```

Comment: `apt-get` и `apt-cache` устарел. Речь про Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: ArcherGodson, ребята из Digital Ocean `apt-get` устаревшим не считают https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-16-04-ru, ниже ссылка почему (на английском) https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: а что считают ребята из Canonical?

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать для таких целей специальные PPA, например эту:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

И после добавления поставить php 5.6 таким образом:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6
```

И нужно будет не забывать, что все пакеты для php, например php-mysql, php-xml нужно будет ставить таким образом:

```
sudo apt install php5.6-mysql 
sudo apt install php5.6-xml
```

P.S. все предыдущие версии php надо удалить

Comment: А как удалить старую версию?
sudo apt-get remove php7.0 не помогает

Comment: @AlievA. зачем её удалять? в настройках сайта достаточно указать версию ,с которой хочется работать. вдруг на другом сайте нужна 7 версия?

Comment: Я 7 версией не собираюсь пользоваться, так как не знаю пока ничего о mysqli. Но проект нужно закончить на 5.6

Comment: @AlievA. mysqli появилась еще в версии 5.0.0 .. Причем тут 7? Судя по этому высказыванию тебе вообще надо основы поучить)) но суть не поменялась. вместо удаления  по тысяче раз версий PHP проще оставить несколько и в настройках сервера выбирать нужную. Тем более весят исходники не гигабайты

Comment: и все же, как поменять на Ubuntu версию PHP?

Comment: @AlievA. `apt purge php*`

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё, но лучше не надо. Следуй за тем, что есть в штатных репах дистрибутива или в официальных репах разработчика конкретного продукта. Потому что когда всё-таки припрёт обновляться (а это происходит всегда) - будет очень весело разгребать авгиевы конюшни из непонятных зависимостей и помойки в `/opt`. А перенос проекта на сервер\другую машину\другому разработчику будет просто сказочной (чем дальше - тем страшнее) задачей. Если сильно хочется поковыряться с чем-то старым - наверное Docker в помощь.

**UPD:** Если сильно позарез нужна именно 5-я ветка php, то как вариант - можно развернуть проект на `ubuntu 14.04`. Он будет поддерживаться до апреля 2019 и за это время уже можно будет замигрировать на php7.

Comment: "Следуй за тем, что есть в штатных репах дистрибутива" не все приложения еще адекватно могут работь с PHP >7.0 так что откат на 5.6 еще часто бывает нужен.

Comment: @SeyDee, ну я написал в upd что делать, если нужна 5-я версия пхп.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Для смены версии по умолчанию в Ubuntu используйте следующую команду.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```